# How to resize UIImage without compromising the image quality?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm converting the image buffer (CVPixelBuffer) to UIImage and, in doing so, I'm changing the orientation as well as the size.

```swift
let image = CIImage(cvImageBuffer: imageBuffer)
let imageSize = CGSize(width: CVPixelBufferGetWidth(imageBuffer), height: CVPixelBufferGetHeight(imageBuffer))
let normalizeTransform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.0 / imageSize.width, y: 1.0 / imageSize.height)
let flipTransform = orientation.isPortrait ? CGAffineTransform(scaleX: -1, y: -1).translatedBy(x: -1, y: -1) : .identity
let viewPortSize: CGSize = viewPort.size
let displayTransform: CGAffineTransform = arFrame.displayTransform(for: orientation, viewportSize: CGSize(width: viewPortSize.width, height: viewPortSize.height))

let scaleX: CGFloat = viewPortSize.width
let scaleY: CGFloat = viewPortSize.height
let viewPortTransform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: scaleX, y: scaleY)

let scaledImage: CIImage = image
    .transformed(by: normalizeTransform
        .concatenating(flipTransform)
        .concatenating(displayTransform)
        .concatenating(viewPortTransform)
    )
    .cropped(to: viewPort)

guard let uiImage: UIImage = self.convert(cmage: scaledImage) else {
    return nil
}
```

(arFrame is ARFrame from ARKit and [displayTransform](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arframe/2923543-displaytransform) is for creating the CGAffineTransform for transforming a normalized image.)

The breakdown of above code is something like this:

1. Scale down the image to normalize the coordinates.
2. Flip the image according to the orientation (some ARKit quirk)
3. Transform the image suited for rendering the camera image onscreen.
4. Scale up the image to fit the camera screen.

One problem I'm facing is that since I'm scaling down the image #1 and enlarging it back up #4, the image quality seems to be severely impacted.  #1 has to come before #4 and can't be combined since #3 has to take in a normalized image.

**Update**

When I try to prevent drastically scaling down the size of the image by doing the following:

```swift
let flipTransform: CGAffineTransform = metadata.orientation.isPortrait ? CGAffineTransform(scaleX: -1, y: -1).translatedBy(x: -1, y: -1) : .identity
let scaleTransform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: scaleX / imageSize.width, y: scaleY / imageSize.height)

let img = image.oriented(cgImagePropertyOrientation)
let scaledImage = img
    .transformed(by: flipTransform
        .concatenating(scaleTransform))
```

the resulting image is cut off by half and the ratio skewed.

[image]

Comment: Step 1 looks wrong to me. You may want to have your coordinates normalized on the side, and use them for calculations, but you definitely don't want to do such a drastic resizing to the original image. So I'd say: get rid of step 1 at all, and make your calculations to be correct for original image size.

Comment: @rapiddevicedo you have any recommendation on how to bypass `displayTransform`?

Comment: `displayTransform` returns normalized coordinates (0,0) - (1,1), which you need to convert to actual image coordinates by multiplying them to width / height of the image (before `.concatenating(displayTransform)`). I.e. don't bring image to the scale of coordinates, bring the coordinates to the scale of the image

Comment: Do you mind giving an example of bringing the coordinates to the scale of the image? I understand the notion of bringing the image to the scale of coordinates, but I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around bringing the coordinates to the scale of the image.

Comment: I'm not really clear what you are trying to achieve, so hard to say. But what if you do this: 1 - remove first step; 2 - step 2 remains the same; 3 - step 3 is something like `let displayTransform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: viewPortSize.width / imageSize.width, y: viewPortSize.height / imageSize.height)`; 4 - remove step 4; 5 - apply 3 transforms the same way (concatenating). So what's missing for you in that result? How is it different from expected?

Comment: My main objective is to preserve the quality of the image as much as possible. So I wanted to bypass having to scale down image as drastically as I did in the question which was required for `displayTransform` since the image coordinates have to be between (0, 0) - (1, 1) for it.  But, when I try to scale down the image using the method you mentioned above `viewPortSize.width / imageSize.width)`, I get an image that is cropped incorrectly.  I have updated the question to show what I mean.

Comment: This is because I did the "fit" type of resize. You can also do `let factor = min(viewPortSize.width / imageSize.width, viewPortSize.height / imageSize.height); CGAffineTransform(scaleX: factor, y: factor)` - that's equivalent of "aspect fit", or `let factor = max(viewPortSize.width / imageSize.width` - that's equivalent of "aspect fill". In aspect fill case you may also need to cut the image with `let extraX = viewPortSize.width * factor - imageSize.width` (and similar for y) CGAffineTransform(translationX: extraX, y: extraY)`

Comment: Sorry I should've clarified. I'm currently cropping the face out of the image using the coordinates of the view port (which is the UIKit coordinate). `arFrame.displayTransform` from my original code allows just that by converting the coordinates to be that of the viewport. The reason the face is cut off in such a way above is because the coordinate of the transformed image is wrong.  How can I ensure the transforming method you mentioned uses the coordinate to the viewport size?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah. @rapiddevice has it right. Scaling your image down is destructive. You need to do the scaling from source image to target resolution once, and keep the pixel count as high as possible to preserve image detail.

Comment: I've tried getting rid of all the transforms and adding `CGAffineTransform(scaleX: scaleX / imageSize.width, y: scaleY / imageSize.height)` to prevent shrinking the image down dramatically, but I can't seem to get the image orientation and the aspect ratio correctly. Do you have any recommendation?